# Autoselect the first form when opening a form list

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a list of forms that have to be compiled by the user. When opening the page I would like the first form the be already selected, so that the user doesn't have to click on it once the page is opened.

Thank you.

This is a little sample, once the page is opened the "Code" form have to be already selected.

```
<div class="formxx">
    <div>
        <label for="txCode" id="codeLabel">Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" name="code" id="txCode"  maxlength="4"  tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="txDescription" id="descLabel">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="txDescription" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I also made a "view" on CodePen, here it is:

https://codepen.io/user23xx/pen/jKRpEe

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Please include all your test code as part of your question. Stack Overflow questions and answers can live for years, long after external sites have purged content and links become invalid.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just use `autofocus` in a input field. example is below

```css
.form-control {
  height:20px
}
#txCode{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#codeLabel{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#descLabel{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="formxx">
            <div>
                <label for="txCode" id="codeLabel">Code</label>
                <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control" style="text-transform:uppercase" name="code" id="txCode"  maxlength="4"  tabindex="1" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="txDescription" id="descLabel">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="txDescription" tabindex="2"
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: good solution! be aware that autofocus is not supported on iOS Safari at the moment, but if you do not need to support this browser this html-only solution is just good, vote up from me :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking of input elements not forms?

You just need to set the focus to the input element, you can do this by javascript:

```
document.getElementById('txCode').focus();
```